# Handling multiple buttons in UIToolbar

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a problem using multiple `UIBarButtonItem`s within a `UIToolbar` on one side of a `UINavigationController`. I‘ve used one of the many examples on how to put multiple buttons in the navigation bar (using a toolbar), and while I got it displaying correctly now, I always get an unkown Objective-C exception thrown when a button is pressed.

This is the full test UIViewController I use for adding multiple buttons:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace TestProject
{
    public class Test : UIViewController
    {
        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            UIBarButtonItem btn1 = new UIBarButtonItem( "foo", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                Console.WriteLine( "asdf" );
            } );

            UIBarButtonItem btn2 = new UIBarButtonItem();
            btn2.Style = UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered;
            btn2.Title = "bar";
            btn2.Clicked += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
                Console.WriteLine( "fdsa" );
            };

            UIToolbar tb = new UIToolbar( new RectangleF( 0, 0, 150, 44.0f ) );
            tb.SetItems( new UIBarButtonItem[] { btn1, btn2 }, false );
            NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem( tb );
        }
    }
}
```

I put that controller within a `UINavigationController` and display its view as the only window content. Everything works fine, until I click one of the buttons:

```
Error connecting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:10001)
Stacktrace:

  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0009f, 0xffffffff>
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26
  at TestProject.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/Apple/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/Main.cs:16
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00050, 0xffffffff>

Native stacktrace:

    0   TestProject                         0x000d0de8 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 343
    1   TestProject                         0x0000f74c mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 322
    2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x906fc45b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   UIKit                               0x01ee6cc3 -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 156
    5   UIKit                               0x01cd44fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    6   UIKit                               0x01d64799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x01d66c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    8   UIKit                               0x01d657d8 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 458
    9   UIKit                               0x01cf8ded -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 567
    10  UIKit                               0x01cd9c37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    11  UIKit                               0x01cdef2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0404f992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00ea2944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00e02cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00dfff83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00dff840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00dff761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x0404e1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x0404e289 GSEventRun + 115
    20  UIKit                               0x01ce2c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    21  ???                                 0x077efe64 0x0 + 125763172
    22  ???                                 0x077ef1e2 0x0 + 125759970
    23  ???                                 0x077ef0be 0x0 + 125759678
    24  ???                                 0x077ef145 0x0 + 125759813
    25  TestProject                         0x0000f507 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1332
    26  TestProject                         0x001ed259 mono_runtime_invoke + 137
    27  TestProject                         0x001ef940 mono_runtime_exec_main + 669
    28  TestProject                         0x001eed2a mono_runtime_run_main + 843
    29  TestProject                         0x000a3093 mono_jit_exec + 200
    30  TestProject                         0x002a163d main + 4060
    31  TestProject                         0x00002819 _start + 208
    32  TestProject                         0x00002748 start + 40

Debug info from gdb:

dyld: could not load inserted library: /Users/Apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/86C48AC1-821F-49DD-B344-58471F02D31B/TestProject.app/monotouch-fixes.dylib


=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Does anyone know what‘s causing this, and more importantly how to avoid it? When setting just a single button as the `RightBarButtonItem` it works without any problems.

#### edit

Above error seems to randomly cycle with this one:

```
Error connecting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:10001)
2011-08-25 13:30:05.409 TestProject[1235:a0b] -[__NSCFSet InvokeAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7168980

Unhandled Exception: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFSet InvokeAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7168980
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26 
  at TestProject.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/Apple/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/Main.cs:16 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFSet InvokeAction:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7168980
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26 
  at TestProject.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/Apple/Projects/TestProject/TestProject/Main.cs:16
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the buttons as class variables. The GC collects them so your event handlers are causing memory leaks.

Comment: Interesting, that worked! Thank you! Is that default behaviour in C#/.NET though? Shouldn‘t the GC know that there are still references to the objects within the toolbar itself?

Comment: It is not default C#/.NET behavior. It is MonoTouch's behavior, whose GC is more brutal.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Then I guess the bug report I filed about this is not totally redundant ;)

Comment: It's not about brutality, .NET GC would do the same (collect) if UIToolbar.SetItems does not keep a reference to the managed object (but only to the native collection). That's a bug in MonoTouch, thanks for filling a bug report!

Comment: Oh that has been around since MT4. I think many people considered it as "normal" behavior and not a bug (including me). Thanks poupou.

Comment: Ideally the C# proxy for the navcon should keep a reference to the C# proxy for the buttonitem. But it doesn't, and it seems to be the "convention" that if the native code is keeping a reference then the managed code isn't. This causes bugs like this. OTOH, if the managed navcon maintained a duplicate set of references, it'd be possible for them to get out of sync, plus the MT team would really have to pay attention to every single property and method (i.e. should it keep a reference or not) and we'd probably not have MT where it is today. In summary: I can live with it.